# Regression model form

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I have the following exercise:

> US.pop dataset from car package contains information about USA population from 1790 to 1990.
>   Find regression model in form of $y = a / (1 + \exp((b-x)/c) )$ for given data.
>   Draw found regression function, check model assumptions.

And here is my code. And I feel stuck. I don't really know how to continue with finding regression model for the given equation and what to do next.

```
# Loading data - US.Pop
data("uspop")
uspop_set <- c(head(uspop, 19))

# Create array with corelated data (jump every 10 years)
year <- seq(1790, 1970, 10)
uspop_set = as.numeric(uspop_set)

# Regression model in form of "y = a / (1 + e^( (b-x)/c) )"
eq = function(a, b, c, x){a / (1 + exp(1)^( (b-x)/c) )}

# Drawing plot
plot(year, uspop_set, type = "l")

# Create linear model
model = lm(year ~ uspop_set)
summary(model)
```

Comment: it's not linear so you can't use lm. check out the nls or nls2 functions and look at the help for those or examples of the use on the net.

Comment: Or, assuming that $x$ and $y$ are continuous, transform your original equation and transform the variables so that the final expression is a linear combination of the parameters and you can apply a linear regression.

Comment: What Ertxiem said is fine but that approach needs to be done carefully because the error term of the original equation gets transformed also. personally, I would go with a non-linear approach. otherwise, you have to worry about what the error term is in the linearized equation.